# Docker command failing on ARM

Tags: git, docker, arm

Getting this error while trying to build redis timeseries container on ARM

```
# docker build -t shantanuo/redistimeseries .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  32.75MB
Step 1/19 : ARG REDIS_VER=6.0.9
Step 2/19 : ARG OSNICK=bionic
Step 3/19 : ARG ARCH=arm64v8
Step 4/19 : FROM redisfab/redis:${REDIS_VER}-${ARCH}-${OSNICK} AS builder
 ---> 1b5e0f2c1672
Step 5/19 : ARG REDIS_VER
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f9d3227c2bb0
Step 6/19 : ADD ./ /build
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 371c631e8952
Step 7/19 : WORKDIR /build
 ---> Using cache
 ---> eeadd76e1639
Step 8/19 : RUN ./deps/readies/bin/getpy3
 ---> Running in bea45f18f407
/bin/sh: 1: ./deps/readies/bin/getpy3: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c ./deps/readies/bin/getpy3' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I have changed the variables ARCH and OSNICK in step 2 and 3

I got the dockerfile from this location:

https://hub.docker.com/r/redislabs/redistimeseries/dockerfile

Is there any easy way to build images for ARM?

Comment: Are you running `docker build` command on `arm64v8` architecture?

Comment: I am using "arm64" as per "dpkg --print-architecture" command. Not sure if it is v8 :)

Answer (score 3):

Did you clone the repository recursively?
It seems that bin/getpy3 is actually included in deps/readies as a git submodule (see [here](https://github.com/RedisTimeSeries/RedisTimeSeries/tree/master/deps)).
You thus might need to update the submodules. You might want to try to initialize the submodule and retry the build :)

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: This worked. But Can you explain a little more about how submodule command helped in this case?

Comment: The RedisTimeSeries repo that you cloned uses code from other repositories. Those modules are not copied but linked as git submodules; their code thus does not live in the RedisTimeSeries but in their repo ["readies"](https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/readies). This separation thus increases code reusability but requires the git client to fetch additional repositories. To clone the repo and the submodules at the same time use the `--recursive` flag as stated in the RedisTimeSeries Readme: `git clone --recursive https://github.com/RedisTimeSeries/RedisTimeSeries.git`

Answer (score 1):

Did you clone https://github.com/RedisTimeSeries/RedisTimeSeries to the directory your dockerfile is in? Step 6 is copying the getpy3 file (and others) into the image, and step 8 (fails) is attempting to run it.

Host side, you're missing `$PWD/deps/readies/bin/getpy3`.

Their github seems to also have an arm flavored dockerfile: https://github.com/RedisTimeSeries/RedisTimeSeries/blob/master/Dockerfile.arm